# Pairing Data from Multiple Deferred Ajax Calls with their Caller

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred

I'm working with multiple deferred Ajax calls and I would like to be dynamic about how I access their data.  Rather than hardcoding in several parameters into the .then callback and using each individually, I would like to loop through the arguments object to access the data.  This works fine, except I'm not able to determine from the json which data is from which Ajax call.  I could solve this either by determining the url from the promise object (somehow) or figuring out which order the Ajax calls executed and assuming the data is in the same order.

Here's my code so far (mocked up for illustrating what I'm trying to do):

```
promises = [ 
    $.get("example.php", {}, function(){}),
    $.get("list.php", {}, function(){}),
    $.get("test.php", {}, function(){}),

]

$.when.apply(null, promises).then( function() {
     jsonarray = []
     $.each(arguments, function(index, value){
         // this is what I would like to work but doesn't
         // promises[index].success.url is how I imagine accessing 
         //"list.php" or "test.php"
         if (jsonarray[promises[index].success.url] == null){
              jsonarray[promises[index].success.url] = []
         }
         jsonarray[promises[index].success.url] = value
         doSomethingWith(jsonarray)
     })
```

Is there another way to match each argument with the Ajax call that produced it?  What I don't want to do is this:

```
$.when.apply(null, promises).then( function(examplejson, listjson, testjson) {
         // this is lame
         exampledoSomethingWith(examplejson)
         listdoSomethingWith(listjson)
         testdoSomethingWith(testjson)
})
```

Thanks!
Sara

Comment: I'm unsure how `apply` works, but wouldn't you be able to add the URL of each call in your `promises` array? You cold possible turn your promises array into an array of objects `promises = [ {url: "example.php", fn: $.get("example.php", {}, function(){})}, ... ]`

Comment: I could do that, but it will complicate getting the jquery promise into the when.apply call.  If you just do a straight ajax call, the promise is returned for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6EZsh/2/

```
$(function() {

    var objs = [{'one':1},{'two':2},{'three':3}];
    var urls = [];

    ajaxCall = function(i) {
        return $.ajax({
            url:'/echo/html/',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {id:i}
        }).done(function () {
            urls.push({obj:i,url:this.url});
        });   
    }

   $.when.apply($,
        objs.map(function(i) {
            return ajaxCall(i);
        })
    ).then(
        console.log(urls)
    );

});
```

As mentioned the object you receive in your "then" are the success handlers for all your deferreds. So the only real way to pair this information would be in the success handler of your Ajax calls. Example above.

Answer (score 0):

let's try

```
var urls = [
    "example.php",
    "list.php",
    "test.php"
];
var promises = [  
];

var jsonarray = {};
$.each(urls, function(index, value) {
    promises[index] = $.get(urls[index], {}, function(){});
    promises[index].success(function(data) {
        jsonarray[urls[index]] = data; //is this the value you want in the jsonarray??
    });
});

$.when.apply(null, promises).then( function() {
    doSomethingWith(jsonarray) 
});
```

Comment: Tried it and I get a type error that the promise object doesn't have a method success.  Thanks for the thoughtful response!

Comment: @saranicole -- I tried a different twist on it.  I'm assuming you want the returned data in your jsonarray, and that it should be keyed by the url?  Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @saranicole what version of jquery are you using? In the latest version, `.success()` has been replaced by `.done()`, so try using that.

Comment: @BrianGlaz -- `success` should always be available. `done` is just the general handler for a deferred/promise

Comment: @Skyrim It's not available in jquery 1.8: "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."

Comment: ah...I hadn't noticed that 1.8 had been released!!  That's cool!  Strange...jquery's site still has 1.7.1, though.

Comment: I am using 1.7 so good to know.  I'm thinking the question might be a bit naive since $.when consolidates all the promises into a single object that has its own success/done property.  When I use $.when I'm giving up the right to know what's up with each individual query.  Probably going to go with not using the deferred object and just keeping them separate queries.  Also, Skyrim for the Nords!